# Rails: Update model attributes. Error Missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a page to edit/update a record, but I am getting this error:

```
Missing template tickets/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views"
```

My tickets controler:

```
    class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy, :index]
  def index
    @tickets = Ticket.all
  end

  def show
        @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])

  end

  def edit 
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    if @ticket.update_attributes(ticket_params)
      flash[:success] = "Ticket atualizado!"
      redirect_to @ticket
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new
    @user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    @ticket.user = current_user

    if @ticket.save
      redirect_to @ticket
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def update
  end

  private

  def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:subject, :body, :status)
  end

end
```

My view edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editar Ticket</h1>

<h2><%= @ticket.subject %></h2>

<div class ="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@ticket) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= f.label :status %>
      <%= f.select :status, ['Aberto', 'Resolvido',  'Fechado', 'Processando']%>

      <p><%= @ticket.body %></p>

      <%= f.submit "Salvar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Server Log:

```
    Processing by TicketsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ljRnDwjCpKhL+Jl4PkQbLiyEESHnVMgQjpt2EJ6QoEhMza03feBRzz3xOAFsjnjWz7+ASAuGn1qKx+gHtUIm7w==", "ticket"=>{"status"=>"Fechado"}, "commit"=>"Salvar", "id"=>"16"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template tickets/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

I wrote this based on another model in the same application which is updating attributes with no errors. 
Already tried changing to `@ticket.update_attributes(params[:ticket])` and other suggestions looking at stackoverflow but no lucky.

What I'm missing here?

Sorry my bad english.

Comment: In the TicketsController, do you accidentally have a second definition of the `update` method that is further down in the file?

Comment: It looks like it is expecting a update.html.erb file in the views/tickets folder.  However the request sent to the update method most likely should be put or patch method which would not require this so I am thinking there is probably something wrong with the route or method with the form.  What is the return of rake routes?  Can you post it?  Is there a post method to the update method?

Comment: @cschroed I don't know how you find out this, but this is the problem! Thank you so much! I will update the question to point the problem, so you can answer properly. (I don't know if this is the right procedure though)

Comment: @cschroed Done! updated the question to entire Tickets.Controller. Waiting for your answer to mark as correct! Thanks again I'm learning Rails and spend the entire day on this =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior for a controller action in Rails is to [render by default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action).  When this happens, Rails will look for a template with the same name as the action.

And Ruby allows you to [redefine methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Overriding), which can be useful when you intend to override the behavior of an existing method.

In this case, the first `update` method you wanted to execute was being overridden by the second `update` method.  The second `update` method did nothing, so by default Rails tried to render a template called `tickets/update`.  This is what led to the `Missing template tickets/update` error.

To resolve this, you will want to delete the unwanted second method.

Comment: Great answer too! It's hard to remember those things reading the documentation, but this one I will never forget! =]